# Почему не работает расширение?

Tags: javascript

Сделал расширения для хрома, чтобы показывало количество изменений динамического z-index. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему ругается хром, вроде всё ровно написано.
Логика была такая:
Создаем 3 переменных->в первую записываем значение z-index->сравниваем значение первой переменной и второй->если переменные не равны->к третьей переменной прибавляем 1->второй переменной присваиваем значение первой.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('[data-id="32"]').style.zIndex;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
 if (b != a) {
  c++;
  b = a;
 };
 
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  // если кнопка - "a" латинская маленькая
  if (e.key === 'a') {
    alert(c);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ну так а чем хром ругается, какая ошибка?

Comment: все зависит от расширения, скорее всего у тебя просто нет доступа к Html страницы, поэтому `document.querySelector('[data-id="32"]')` возвращает null

Comment: Можете уточнить про доступ к HTML страницы, и как его получить? А так, да, выдается null

Comment: Может вместо `document.body.addEventListener`  `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: @Алексей, что у тебя в манифесте?